# I cannot install Pepper Flash on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ppa, flash, chromium

I understand that the original version of Adobe's Flash is deprecated for security reasons, and that we should use Pepper Flash instead.

However, I cannot install Pepper Flash on Ubuntu 16.04. (I use Chromium, not Firefox.)

I have [followed the instructions](https://launchpad.net/~skunk/+archive/ubuntu/pepper-flash) to add the repository `ppa:skunk/pepper-flash`, which worked, and continues to work, perfectly on 14.04.

But, on 16.04, when I reload the repositories, I get this error:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Is this something that I have done incorrectly? How can I fix this?

Comment: Looking at https://launchpad.net/~skunk/+archive/ubuntu/pepper-flash, it looks like the PPA doesn't provide an installation candidate for 16.04, so the PPA is basically useless for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable Canonical Partners repository in System Settings -> Software & Updates, then run in terminal

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
```

This will install Pepper Flash.

There is no need to use a PPA.

Comment: Are you sure that this is Pepper Flash and not Adobe's deprecated Flash?

Comment: This will install both. I am using it on Chromium. I AM sure.

Answer (score 0):

Im never use PPA for Pepper Flash. I only install Chrome browser and create symlink to Pepper Flash and launch Chromium or directly launch chromium with command line to this flash and all work fine. Look below.

Command line to run chromium with pepper flash `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --ppapi-flash-path=/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so`

You can also add this Flag permament to all Chromium launch.

Comment: But you'd (probably) have Google Chrome installed for this to work, which comes with Flash built in.