# how to solve this problem on my ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: updates

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: is it the output of your 'sudo apt update'?

Comment: Don't use a PPA to install that -- it's out of date, and there are no new releases for your 16.04+ release (aka xenial; see code names here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases ) .  Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/805639/i-cannot-install-pepper-flash-on-ubuntu-16-04/805641

Comment: Note that "16.04" is an Ubuntu release from "2016" (16.x), April (month 04).  Ubuntu releases in April (04) and October (10), so you should consider _updating_ (to latest software for 16.04) and then _upgrading_ to 16.10 and then _upgrading_ again to 17.04.

Comment: yes sir it is the out put of "sudo apt-get update"                      then how can i update my system to install mysql .Basically i was trying to install mysql on my system ubuntu 16.04 LTS.